# how do i query in mongo db using like operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want query something based on `date(11/11/2016)` using `like` operator:

How to do the same in mongodb?

```
db.getCollection('TableName').find({"Date":/.*10/11/2016.*/})
```

I tried with this query but getting `invalid result`.

Comment: Is date is stored as string?

Comment: yes lakshmipriya.
Got the result just tried with this Query db.getCollection('TableName').find({"Date":/.*11\/11\/2016 .*/})

Answer (score 4):

There is no `like` in mongo,You can use `regex`
Here in this case you dont require regex,you can get your result using simple find query,Date stored in mongodb is in `ISO` formate,So first convert your date to `ISO date` and then find for eg

```
var convertDate = "11/11/2016";
convertDate  = new Date(11/11/2016);
db.getCollection('TableName').find({date : convertDate})
```

Or if you want `like` in mongo use this

1)Search directly

```
db.getCollection('TableName').find({date : {$regex : "11/11/2016"}})
```

2)
Create a text index on date and then search

```
db.getCollection('TableName').find({$text:{$search:"11/11/2016"}})
```

Answer (score -1):

Like/Regex in Mongodb can be done by `.` when you have `/` in value.

To get date starting with `10/11/`, try this for your query:

```
db.getCollection('TableName').find({'Date':/^10.11./})
```